# Angular expression is not working in ternary operator

Tags: angularjs

I just started to work with Angular, it seems good to implement and I am enjoying it.

I just used ternary operator in my `HTML` page, but it's not working and I am getting Angular `parsing error`

Here is the stuff which I am trying to execute.

```
<button class="common btnYellow viewAllText">{{data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name.length>=0 ? '{{data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name}}' : 'Recently Added'}}</button>
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

> {{data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name.length>=0 ? '{{data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name}}' : 'Recently Added'}}

With this:

> {{data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name.length>=0 ? data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name : 'Recently Added'}}

```
<button class="common btnYellow viewAllText">{{data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name.length>=0 ? data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name : 'Recently Added'}}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to nest interpolation expressions together.

Use this :

```
<button class="common btnYellow viewAllText">{{data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name.length>=0 ? data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name : 'Recently Added'}}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

{{data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name.length>=0 ? data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name : 'Recently Added'}}

Answer (score 1):

You have already used the angular expression parser so you don't have to repeat it again.
You don't have to add the `''` for the angular expression either.

Also, use braces to make the expressions more clearer -

```
<button class="common btnYellow viewAllText">
    {{ (data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name.length >= 0) ? 
    data.data.bookmarks[0].category_name : 'Recently Added' }}
</button>
```